# UPDATE database field with value from other table

Tags: 7, database

I'm basically trying to build a query which looks something like:

```sql
UPDATE table_a, table_b
SET table_a.value = table_b.value
WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id;
```

It seems that a query like this is functionally equivalent:

```sql
UPDATE table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
  ON table_a.id = table_b.id
SET table_a.value = table_b.value;
```

The thing is that I can't figure out how the UpdateQuery allows me to attach a second table like that. I tried just adding a `->join('table_b')` to my update query object, but I'm told that method is undefined. Argh.

I've ended up cheating by using `db_query()`, though I'm still curions to know if there's a way to do this properly using the API.

Comment: are you using D6 or D7?

Comment: D7. (Tag added.)

Comment: I faced the same problem. Seems there is no `join()` method for `UpdateQuery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the specific nature of your SQL statement, it would appear db_query() is the way to go. Just be sure to do it as an update hook in your .install (so you can drush updb) to implement smoothly.

Comment: You mean use `hook_update_N()`? I'm not sure if that was relevant to my issue (note that this question is nearly two years old)… but at any rate, yeah, I guess my suspicions are confirmed and cheating with `db_query()` is all I could do in this case.

Comment: Yes, I meant hook_update_xxx() @GarrettAlbright